# Docker build target is ignored in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm facing a problem to build a docker image in a bitbucket pipeline. I'm using the bitbucket cloud hosted solution, not a self-hosted runner.

I have a `Dockerfile` with multiple [build stages](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#name-your-build-stages). When running the following command in the bitbucket pipeline, the `--target` option is ignored.

step:

```yaml
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &build-staging
        name: Build staging
        services:
        - docker
        script:
          - docker build -t image_name --target staging .
```

I didn't find any mention of a limitation regarding multi-stage build in the documentation about [running docker commandes in bitbucket pipelines](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/run-docker-commands-in-bitbucket-pipelines/#Running-Docker-commands). Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Bitbucket issue, but the Docker itself. BuildKit fixes this bug in multi-stage builds in the legacy docker build engine.

So, just enable the BuildKit by inserting the line

```
- export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
```

before the `docker build ...` command and the image will be built with the specified target.